# Error while loading Laravel 500 server error

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan

I'm running Laravel on my localhost, however when I follow the http address I get a 500 server error. 
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

````
C:\Users\insaloon\Gram>php artisan serve

Laravel development server started: <http://127.0.0.1:8000>
[Fri Jun  7 16:03:04 2019] 127.0.0.1:57415 [200]: /favicon.ico
[Fri Jun  7 16:03:09 2019] 127.0.0.1:57420 [200]: /favicon.ico
[Fri Jun  7 16:09:00 2019] 127.0.0.1:57505 [200]: /favicon.ico

[![this is exactly what am getting][2]][2]

```[![This is what am suppose to get][3]][2[![\]
][4]][4]I've done `composer install` and `composer update`.


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHpW4.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/egiDL.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4w5Z.png
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rgtm9.png
````

Comment: You have apparently tried to add an image with the error to your question, but you have not done it correctly. Please, edit the question so that we can see the image or paste the trace of the error as text in the question.

Comment: When an error 500 occurs, it shows some trace of the error. Post it otherwise we can't help you. Error 500 usually are caused by php syntax error, file permissions and some other causes

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it...
I just needed to create a new .env file in my platform copy everything that was in my .env.example
run php artisan key: generate
then php artisan serve

Then....VOILA problem resolue (problem solved!)